# Can't Add Navigation Item in Xamarin iOS in NavigatioNController inside TabController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to add a NavigationItem to my Navbar put when I deploy it on my device it will not show up.

I think it's similar to the tutorial on the xamarin website.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public class LinksPageController : UINavigationController
    {
        public LinksPageController ()
        {
            NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (183, 28, 28);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
                new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, (sender,args) => {
                    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Add link!", "Enter the ID of the person you want to be linked with:", null, "Cancel", "OK");
                    alert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
                    alert.Show ();
                })
                , true);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to add an icon or some text for the button itself to be able to see/click it?

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Post the code on how you're creating your custom Navigation Controller and adding it to your TabController.  Maybe you've left something out there.

Answer (score 0):

How about instantiating a class button before adding it to the navBar? could it be that you are losing the instance pointer..??

```
UIBarButtonItem * newButton;
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        newButton =  new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, (sender,args) => {
                UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Add link!", "Enter the ID of the person you want to be linked with:", null, "Cancel", "OK");
                alert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
                alert.Show ();
            })

        this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(newButton, true);
    }
```

Comment: i manged to fix my problem. i had a navigation controller which i did not set as a root view controller so the methods were never called. but thank you!